# Remote access over internet via third party application

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, remote-access

I have a wireless IP camera (D-link DCS-932L) at home that I connect wirelessly to my WiFi router by storing my Wifi SSID and password into it. I can access the camera through my phone via a designated application both locally (local LAN) and through the internet. My question is concerning connection over the internet (outside my local network).

I know that in order to initiate a connection to this camera I will need to port forward a specific port to the camera's IP in the router but this is not the case as my camera works without any port forwarding settings on my router. I can only assume that the connection to the application server is initiated from the camera and the connection is kept open. If so how is it kept open? Isn't there a timeout timer for the connection? Does it keep sending test packets before the timeout timer expires? If so how often? What is the best practice in order to verify that the connection is up but at the same time not overwhelm the server with test packets (assuming that this product was sold to millions of users)?

Sorry for the long list of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enabled via the [D-Link "mydlink" cloud service](http://mydlink.dlink.com/products/DCS-932L).  The camera opens up a connection to the D-Link servers which your app also contacts when it's time to watch the video output.  You can contact D-Link customer service to find out if they have any uptime commitment.  If the camera loses its connection to the cloud service, it is supposed to reconnect automatically.

To get details on how it works, you'll need to use a program like tcpdump/wireshark to view the packets on your network (or someone else who already has can add to this answer).

This means that you'll need to (at least temporarily) setup your network as follows: Camera connects via wifi to your computer (turn on ICS or Internet Sharing depending on Win/Mac), your computer connects to your router via a different wireless card or via ethernet.  Now you can run wireshark on your computer and see the packets coming and going.

It makes no practical difference on bandwidth savings if the connection opens and closes several times per day or stays open for days at a time.  And how long the connection stays open depends entirely on how the firmware in the camera is configured, the stability of your internal network, how reliable your ISP is, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I haven't used tcpdump but if it is similar to wireshark then it monitors the traffic coming in and out the device it is installed on (i.e. my PC) which is no use since traffic is going through my CAM via the router. How can I monitor the traffic passing through my CAM or router?

Comment: And is it possible to keep the connection open indefinitely? Will that reserve any bandwidth? Or are you suggesting that it is kept open until it times out and then it reconnects again? I think it make more sense to send a test packet every now and then to keep it open rather than initiating a new connection after time out.

Comment: I updated my post with answers to your questions in the comments.